# Kill the incoming call screen and move him to background?

Tags: android, process, call, kill

I want to move the incoming call screen to the background or kill it.

I tried to kill the process `com.android.phone` once call is arriving but this action disables the signal for 10-20 seconds.

Did I kill the wrong process?

Comment: Please stop shouting.

Answer (score 0):

From android Documentation of [killProcess](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29)

Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's packages/application and any additional processes created by that app; packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's processes.

Therefore you should note that this will only work for rooted phones.